# Unable to upgrade from 12.04

Tags: 12.04, do-release-upgrade

I'm trying to **upgrade from 12.04** but have been unable to do so.

Both, `sudo do-release-upgrade` and `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` have generated the same response:

```
no new release found.
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt upgrade`?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. If it gives you a bunch of updates, install them, reboot, then try those commands again.

Comment: I get no updates to install when I try those commands.

Answer (score 0):

Your OS is almost at it's end of it's support life and is currently in late maintenance support, so OS upgrades may not be available for your OS. Take a look at [this link](https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life) for more info.

Comment: Upgrades to a new release are available until EOL.

Comment: so how can I upgrade from my current OS?